# JSTL solution for providing space between capital letters

Tags: jstl, jstl-functions

Is there any way to provide space between Capital Letters.

```
Eg. I have a jstl expression ${platName} which outputs  AmazonEcho

What I need as output is  Amazon Echo.
```

I tried a few jstl functions but it didn`t help.

Comment: Take a step back. How would you do it in plain Java? Once you get that to work, simply wrap in a custom EL function.

Comment: import java.io.*;
    public class Test {

       public static void main(String args[]) {
          String Str = new String("AmazonEcho");

         String output = Str.replaceAll("(\\p{Ll})(\\p{Lu})","$1 $2");

          System.out.print("Return Value :"+output );;
       }
}

Comment: This prints Amazon Echo, then how to wrap in custom function

Comment: Thanks @BalusC it worked

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked

```
${platName.replaceAll("(\\p{Ll})(\\p{Lu})","$1 $2")}
```